# Restructuring the unit and integration tests in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, integration-testing

I want to split the unit and integration tests in my spring boot (maven) project as shown in the below image.

[image]

Can you please help me with the plugins needed for the maven pom.xml and steps need to be performed to execute the unit and integration tests seperately.

Also I do not want to put the restrictions on the java file naming conventions like *IT.java for Integration tests and *Test.java for unit tests. Independent of file naming convention, whatever the tests present in "integration_tests" directory should be executed for integration tests, What ever present in "unit_tests" directory should be executed for unit tests.

Comment: Keep the default structure as it and use Naming conventions for that which are already existing unit tests `*Test.java` and integration tests `*IT.java` (using maven-failsafe-plugin)... follow convention over configuration... The required violates the convention over configuration paradigm...Why is there a problem to name unit tests and integration tests according to some naming convention?

Comment: because that would put the integration tests and unit tests in the same package structures.

Comment: So what's the problem with that? You can change the package for the integration tests...